# Firefox: iframe printing broken when iframe height more than page height

Tags: firefox, iframe

I have used an Iframe in my html page. That Iframe height: 2500px. When I use the Print Preview. The iframe only partially appears on page 1. There is no page 2 /3 ...pages. Thats appear only one page and other pages complete blank.

Comment: you could use a separate css sheet that is only for printing

Comment: I have used css for Print. But I couldn't get any result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug unfortunately: [Bug 113217 - iframe printing broken when iframe height more than page height](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113217)