# Mozilla and Opera print only one page when html contains iframe

Tags: iframe, printing, opera, mozilla

The same issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937753/firefox-iframe-printing-broken-when-iframe-height-more-than-page-height#_=_) but not answered.

When I try to print Html page with 'iframe', only first page is printed.

Steps to reproduce:
1. Create page.html with content:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe width='50px' height='2500px' src='iframe.html'/>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Create iframe.html with content:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt condimentum tellus ultricies aliquet. Integer iaculis iaculis diam, eget hendrerit justo facilisis nec. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis tristique est vitae viverra. Fusce at nibh ligula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ultrices ullamcorper turpis in tristique. Pellentesque quis turpis dignissim eros volutpat scelerisque ac tincidunt dui. In pellentesque lacus rutrum magna aliquet mollis. Quisque sit amet dui eu ligula blandit pulvinar. Nulla semper neque ac mi tincidunt facilisis. Nulla et blandit mauris.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

3. Open page.html in Opera or Mozilla and go to 'Print Preview' form.

Observed: Only one page in preview, which contains part of content of 'iframe.html'.

Expected: Two or more pages in preview with all content of 'iframe'.

The issue is reproducible in Firefox and Opera. Not reproducible with Chrome.

Comment: solution: _do not put iframe content to `print version` pages_. Alternatively, you can fill a bug in Firefox Bugzilla and Opera Bug Wizard, then wait until it will be fixed (considering the low importance of printing now and the downward trend.. the bug has very low chance to be fixed ever).

Comment: unlikely it will be fixed soon. Printing is indeed a mess in Opera and it is a known bug in Opera bug tracker. That said I'm not clear if stackoverflow is appropriate for this type of questions.